# Add parent ID to body_class

Tags: body-class

What's the best way to add the Parent ID of a page to the `<body <?php body_class(); ?>>`function?

I am currently using the below function to get the Parent ID of a menu item for a different use; any idea how to get that into the body class?

```
function get_menu_parent_ID( $menu_name ) {
    if ( ! isset( $menu_name ) ) {
        return "No menu name provided in arguments";
    }
    $menu_slug  = $menu_name;
    $locations  = get_nav_menu_locations();
    $menu_id    = $locations[$menu_slug];
    $post_id    = get_the_ID();
    $menu_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items( $menu_id );
    $parent_item_id = wp_filter_object_list( 
        $menu_items, array( 'object_id' => $post_id ), 'and', 'menu_item_parent' );
    $parent_item_id = array_shift( $parent_item_id );
    function checkForParent( $parent_item_id, $menu_items ) {
        $parent_post_id = wp_filter_object_list( 
            $menu_items, array( 'ID' => $parent_item_id ), 'and', 'object_id' );
        $parent_item_id = wp_filter_object_list( 
            $menu_items, array( 'ID' => $parent_item_id ), 'and', 'menu_item_parent' );
        $parent_item_id = array_shift( $parent_item_id );
        if ( $parent_item_id == "0" ) {
            $parent_post_id = array_shift( $parent_post_id );
            return $parent_post_id;
        } else {
            return checkForParent( $parent_item_id, $menu_items );
        }
    }
    if ( ! empty( $parent_item_id ) ) {
        return checkForParent( $parent_item_id, $menu_items );
    } else {
        return $post_id;
    }
}
```

Then printing it in a template like so:

```
$parentID = get_menu_parent_ID( 'primary' );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the **body_class** filter

```
// Use the filter 'body_class'
add_filter( 'body_class', 'parent_id_body_class' );
function parent_id_body_class( $classes ) {
    // add parent id number to the $classes array
    $classes[] = wp_get_post_parent_id( $post_ID );
    // return the $classes array
    return $classes;
}
```

Anyway, I recommend you to add some text to the id number, in order to make it more comprehensive, as follows:

```
// Use the filter 'body_class'
add_filter( 'body_class', 'parent_id_body_class' );
function parent_id_body_class( $classes ) {
    // add comprehensive text followed by parent id number to the $classes array
    $classes[] = 'parent-id-' . wp_get_post_parent_id( $post_ID );
    // return the $classes array
    return $classes;
}
```

I hope it helps.